# Not getting values in the attribute annotated by @ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
package com.xxx.yyy.entity;

import com.xxx.yyy.model.Role;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "USER")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;


    @ElementCollection(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "USER_ROLES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME")
    )
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

The corresponding repository class:

```
package com.xxx.yyy.repository.mysql;

import com.xxx.yyy.entity.UserEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, String> {
}
```

The 'Role' Object is an ENUM as below:

```
package com.xxx.yyy.model;

public enum Role {
    ADMIN("Admin"),
    USER("User")

    private final String value;

    Role(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have the following tables:

- USER with column USERNAME (PRIMARY KEY). There is a foreign key linking the USER table with USER_ROLES by the column USERNAME.
- USER_ROLES with columns USERNAME, ROLE (Both are primary keys - composite key).

I am calling the method findById in the repository UserRepository. I get the result alright. But I am not getting the 'roles' list in the UserEntity populated. I have not errors. Except that there is never value in the role list. I checked both the USER and USER_ROLES tables. I have a an entry having the same USERNAME in both the tables. The 'ROLE' for this username is 'ADMIN'.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging for hibernate to see the queries issued and if it shows something that helps identify the issue. Also check how you are persisting, merging and modifying instances. If you are reading from a single EntityManager instance and keeping it around, it could be that it has a stale (or modified) view of your entity cached - you can try clearing it (em.clear) or refreshing the instance, but if that is the case, you'll want to manage its lifecycle and possibly close and reobtain it at key points.

Comment: There are two different SQL queries being executed. One on the USER table, which gets all the records by username, and another on the USER_ROLES table getting record by username. I executed both queries on MySQL and both worked fine. However I do not know whether these are the queries to be executed in this case. Is it supposed to be a join query?

Comment: That was why I was suggesting you turn on application logging so it shows you the queries it is actually executing to fetch your data. Could be an inconsistency in what you are expecting from what you have mapped and is being queried. Or could be something else with the cached entity being returned.

Comment: The application logging is on. That's how I know that two separate SQL select queries were being executed like I said before. But I don't know what query should be executed there